# What is the sscanf placeholder for uint8_t types?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

What is the sscanf placeholder for uint8_t types? I tried %u, but gcc under OS X doesn't like it.

Answer (score 7):

The `SCNu8` macro from `inttypes.h` provides it.

Also note that C has string literal concatenation, i.e. this works:

```
scanf("%d %" SCNu8 " %d", &int_a, &uint8_t_b, &int_c);
```